# Problema de acceso en CentOS 7

Tags: centos

Tengo problemas para acceder a *CentOS 7*, aparece mi usuario e ingreso mi clave y posteriormente me aparece un mensaje momentáneo:

> [FAILED] FAILED TO START RECOVERY KERNEL ARMING, SEE 'SYSTEMACTL KDUMP.SERVICE FOR DETAILS´ [OK] CREATE SLICE USER SLIVE OF GDM

Mi pregunta es, ¿Cómo puedo acceder?

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a [esta pregunta](https://superuser.com/questions/1463319/how-to-fix-failed-to-start-crash-recovery-kernel-arming-when-can-not-enter-the/1463321) en SuperUser, los pasos a seguir son:

1. iniciar el sistema
2. Presionar <kbd>e</kbd> para edit mode
3. Usar las teclas de navegación (flechas) para encontrar `crashkernel=auto`
4. Cambiarlo a `crashkernel=128M` o `crashkernel=256M`
5. Presionar <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> para iniciar el sistema
6. Cambiar `crashkernel=auto` en el archivo `/etc/grub2.cfg` como en el paso 4.
7. Reiniciar el sistema